# Proof of impossibility (or counterexample) for tan(x) = infinity, for floating-point values

Tags: c, floating-point, trigonometry

The [POSIX page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tan.html) of the `tan` function family (`tan`, `tanf`, `tanl`) in C says that:

> If the correct value would cause overflow, a range error shall occur and tan(), tanf(), and tanl() shall return ±HUGE_VAL, ±HUGE_VALF, and ±HUGE_VALL, respectively, with the same sign as the correct value of the function.

However, in practice it is *very* difficult to actually obtain +∞ or −∞ as a computed result in such cases, since the floating-point number would need to be so close to an odd multiple of π/2 that its tangent would be larger than the maximum representable floating-point value of that type. Due to the spacing of representable values, we cannot always get as close to a particular real number as we would like.

Empirically, I am unable to obtain such results with a standard glibc, even using the `nextafter` functions to obtain the closest possible values to π/2 (using `atan(1) * 2` as "half π", and proceeding from there, either to the left or the right of it).

Exhaustive testing of all (32-bit) `float`s confirms this is true for 32 bits, at least in my library. Testing the vicinity of π/2 for `double`s and `long double`s suggests this is also the case for them. However, exhaustive testing is a bit too long: I'd need to test the vicinity of (2k+1)•π/2, for all k ∈ ℤ such that (2k+1)•π/2 is in the floating-point finite range.

So, is there some mathematical or practical argument that allows one to conclude that, at least with “reasonably accurate” library implementations (*e.g.*, with some measured ULP bounds as is done for the [GNU C library math functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html)), the precision of floating-point values will always be such that `tan(x)` will fit in a finite representation of these values? In other words, that `tan` does not grow faster towards infinity than we can get closer to π/2?

Note that I'm excluding `tan(NAN)` and `tan(INFINITY)` from the discussion, since these are documented corner cases which return NaN. Also, it might be possible to obtain different results with subnormal numbers, but since they only occur near zero and not near π/2, I believe we can exclude them.

Therefore, I'm looking for either some mathematical argument/proof/exhaustive test that shows this does not happen, or simply a counterexample where it does, with any standard C library implementation, such that including `<math.h>` and calling `tan` does it; but excluding specific libraries with non-standard `tan`-like functions.

Comment: May I ask why you need such a proof?

Comment: It allows specifying a simpler contract for the `tan` function, as in: "if x is finite, then tan(x) is also finite".

Comment: See [Searching Worst Cases of a One-Variable Function Using Lattice Reduction by Damien Stehlé, Vincent Lefèvre, and Paul Zimmerman in 2005](https://www.vinc17.net/research/papers/ieeetc2005-wclr.pdf) or [their 2002 paper Worst Cases and Lattice Reduction](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071999/document). I have done the analysis in the course of implementing trigonometric functions. From memory, for IEEE-754 binary64, no `tan` value is anywhere near large enough to overflow.

Comment: It's simple but it also provides no freedom for the implementation and is hard to verify for anything beyond 32 bits.

Comment: Also, Jean-Michel Muller shows Maple code for the search in *Elementary Functions: Algorithms and Implementation* (currently available on Amazon.com as an ebook). And says the worst case for a multiple of π/2 in IEEE-754 binary64 is 6381956970095103•2^797.

Comment: Indeed @Eric, I fixed the formula, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a practical demonstration that a correctly-rounded `tan(x)` is never infinite for any finite IEEE 754 binary64 double `x`; in fact, it can never exceed `2.2e+18`. The same approach would work for a 64-bit precision `long double` type, but the search would take a little longer. It should even be feasible for the IEEE 754 binary128 and binary256 floating-point formats. Going beyond that, heuristic arguments suggest that it's *extremely* unlikely that `tan(x)` could overflow for any IEEE 754 binary floating-point format, but I'm not aware of any proof, and I suspect no known proof exists.

Clearly it's enough to consider only positive finite floats (here and below, "float" means IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point value). Every such float has the form `m * 2^e` for some integers `m` and `e` with `0 < m < 2^53` and `-1074 <= e <= 971`.

So we want to find integers `n`, `m` and `e` minimising the absolute value `|n π/2 - m 2^e|`, subject to constraints `0 < n`, `0 < m < 2^53` and `-1074 <= e <= 971`. We're actually only interested in *odd* values of `n`, but the optimal `n` will already be odd: if it's even, then we can halve `n` and decrement `e` to halve the absolute value. Moreover, it's clear that there's little point examining `e` smaller than `-53`, so we can further restrict to `-53 <= e <= 971`.

For any particular fixed value of `e`, our problem is equivalent to finding positive integers `m` and `n` that minimise the absolute value `|n - m 2^(e+1)/π|`, subject to the constraint `m < 2^53`. If we can solve this problem efficiently, we can iterate over the `1025` distinct values of `e` to pull out the overall best solution.

But the subproblem for fixed exponent `e` can be solved by finding the continued-fraction expansion of `2^(e+1) / π`: standard number-theoretic results state that the minimum of `|n - m 2^(e+1) / π|` is guaranteed to come from either a convergent or a semi-convergent `n / m` to `2^(e+1) / π`. All we have to do is find the best convergent or semi-convergent whose denominator is strictly smaller than `2^53`. In practice, the continued fraction expansion allows us to find both the best convergent or semi-convergent (subject to the constraint the the denominator is less than `2^53`) that's strictly *greater* than `|2^(e+1) / π|`, and separately the best convergent or semi-convergent (with similarly constrained denominator) that's strictly *smaller* than `|2^(e+1) / π|`, and then a comparison is needed to determine which of the two convergents is closer.

Here's some Python code that implements the above, and ends up finding the same best approximation already mentioned in the comments. First, a handful of imports that we'll need later on:

```py
from fractions import Fraction
from math import floor, ldexp
```

We'll need an approximation for `π/2`. In fact, we'll need a pair of approximations: a lower and an upper bound. We'll use the first 1000 digits of `π`, since they're well documented and easy to find online (though it turns out that in practice we actually only need around 330 digits). With those digits, we create `Fraction` instances `HALF_PI_LOWER` and `HALF_PI_UPPER` representing tight lower and upper bounds for `π/2`:

```py
# Approximation to π, given by the first 1000 digits after the point. (source:
# https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/1000_places/)
PI_APPROX = Fraction("".join("""
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
  58209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
  82148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128
  48111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196
  44288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091
  45648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
  72458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436
  78925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094
  33057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548
  07446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912
  98336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798
  60943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132
  00056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872
  14684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235
  42019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960
  51870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859
  50244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881
  71010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303
  59825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778
  18577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989
""".split()))

# True value of π is within ERROR of the value given above.
ERROR = Fraction("1e-1000")

HALF_PI_LOWER = (PI_APPROX - ERROR) / 2
HALF_PI_UPPER = (PI_APPROX + ERROR) / 2
```

Now for the continued fraction machinery. First, we give a generator function that generates the sequence of continued fraction coefficients for a value when provided with lower and upper bounds for that value. Essentially this computes the coefficients for the lower and upper bounds separately, and while those coefficients match they're yielded to the caller. As soon as they don't match we don't have enough information to determine the next coefficient, and the function will raise an exception at that point (either `RuntimeError` or `ZeroDivisionError`). We don't much care which exception is raised: we're relying on our original approximations to be accurate enough that we never hit that exception.

```py
def continued_fraction_coefficients(lower: Fraction, upper: Fraction):
    """
    Generate continued fraction coefficients for a positive number.

    Given rational lower and upper bounds for a postive rational or irrational
    number, generate the known coefficients of the continued fraction
    representation of that number. The tighter the lower and upper bounds, the
    more coefficients will be known.

    Raises RuntimeError or ZeroDivisionError when there's insufficient
    information to determine the next coefficient.
    """
    while (q := floor(lower)) == floor(upper):
        yield q
        lower, upper = 1/(upper - q), 1/(lower - q)
    raise RuntimeError("Insufficient resolution")
```

Next, here's a function that consumes this sequence of continued fraction coefficients to produce best lower and best upper approximations (for a given limit on the denominator) to the corresponding value. It generates successive convergents from the continued fraction sequence, and after the denominator limit is exceeded it backtracks to find the best bounds that fit within the denominator limit.

```py
def best_bounds(coefficients, max_denominator):
    """
    Find best lower and upper bounds under a given denominator bound.

    *coefficients* is the sequence of continued fraction coefficients
    for the value we're approximating.

    *max_denominator* is the limit on the denominator.

    Returns the best lower approximation and the best upper approximation
    to the value being approximated, for the given limit on the denominator.
    """
    # a/b and c/d are the closest convergents so far
    # sign is 1 if a/b < value < c/d, and -1 otherwise.

    a, b, c, d, sign = 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
    for q in coefficients:
        a, b, c, d, sign = c, d, a + q * c, b + q * d, -sign
        if max_denominator < d:
            correction = (max_denominator - d) // b
            c, d = c + correction * a, d + correction * b
            break

    if sign == 1:
        return Fraction(a, b), Fraction(c, d)
    else:
        return Fraction(c, d), Fraction(a, b)
```

Now we write a dedicated function that for a fixed exponent `e` minimises `|n π/2 - m 2^e|` over all `n` and `m` with `m < 2^53`. If returns two triples `(x, n, error)` where `x` is the floating-point value `m 2^e`, represented as a Python `float`, and `error` gives the error in the approximation, also converted to a float. (So the `error` values aren't perfectly exact, but they're close enough to allow us to find the best overall approximation.) The two triples represent the best lower and upper bounds.

```py
def best_for_given_exponent(e):
    """
    Find best lower and upper approximations for 2^e / (π/2)
    with denominator smaller than 2**53.

    Returns two triples of the form (x, n, error), where:

    - x is a float close to an integer multiple of π/2
    - n is the coefficient of that integer multiple of π/2
    - error is the absolute error |x - n π/2|, rounded to the nearest float.

    The first triple gives a best lower approximation for a multiple of π/2,
    while the second triple gives a best upper approximation.
    """
    twopow = Fraction(2)**e
    coefficients = continued_fraction_coefficients(twopow/HALF_PI_UPPER, twopow/HALF_PI_LOWER)
    best_lower, best_upper = best_bounds(coefficients, max_denominator=2**53 - 1)

    n, d = best_lower.as_integer_ratio()
    lower_result = ldexp(d, e), n, float(d * twopow - n * HALF_PI_LOWER)

    n, d = best_upper.as_integer_ratio()
    upper_result = ldexp(d, e), n, float(n * HALF_PI_UPPER - d * twopow)

    return lower_result, upper_result
```

Finally, we put this all together to find the overall best binary64 approximation to an odd multiple of `π/2`.

```py
all_results = [
    result for e in range(-53, 972)
    for result in best_for_given_exponent(e)
]
x, n, error = min(all_results, key=lambda result: result[2])

print(f"Best approximation: {x.hex()} is an approximation to {n}*π/2 with approximate error {error}")
```

When I run this on my machine, it gives the following output (after around 5 seconds of computation):

```py
Best approximation: 0x1.6ac5b262ca1ffp+849 is an approximation to 3386417804515981120643892082331156599120239393299838035242121518428537554064774221620930267583474709602068045686026362989271814411863708499869721322715946622634302011697632972907922558892710830616034038541342154669787134871905353772776431251615694251273653*π/2 with approximate error 4.687165924254628e-19
```

So the overall worst case is the floating-point number `0x1.6ac5b262ca1ffp+849`, which matches the value `6381956970095103•2^797` quoted by Eric Postpischil in a comment on the original question:

```py
>>> float.fromhex('0x1.6ac5b262ca1ffp+849') == ldexp(6381956970095103, 797)
True
```

The tangent of that value will be roughly `±1/4.687165924254628e-19`, or `2.133485385753704e+18`, and indeed that's the value that the math library on my machine produces:

```py
>>> from math import tan
>>> tan(float.fromhex('0x1.6ac5b262ca1ffp+849'))
-2.133485385753704e+18
```

Thus no finite binary64 float has a tangent exceeding `2.133485385753704e+18`.

Answer (score 4):

> ... is there some mathematical or practical argument that allows one to conclude that, ... the precision of floating-point values will always be such that tan(x) will fit in a finite representation of these values?

π is an irrational number, as is `some_odd_integer*π/2` - the poles of math *tangent(some_radian_measure)*.

All finite floating point values are rational numbers.  Thus no `double` is an integer multiple of π/2 and `tan(some_finite_double)` is never a pole.

`some_odd_n*π/2` may be very near a `double a` like 6381956970095103 ∗ 2<sup>797</sup>.  When this is true, then `tan(a)` is large.

This is close to [K.C. Ng's "ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit"  Chapter 2.3](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Ephatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf).  This roughly implies a closest case difference for about 2<sup>-62</sup> off of `some_odd_n*π/2` for all `double`.  Such a value `a` off of a `some_odd_n*π/2` by 2<sup>-62</sup> results in a `tan()` of *about* 2<sup>62</sup>, well within `double` range of 2<sup>1023</sup>.

This key point is that for some FP type to have `tan(a)` exceed FP_MAX, `a` must be *very close* to `some_odd_n*π/2`, on the order of log2(FP_MAX).  That is not *very* likely to happen with wider FP types as precision is linear and the range exponential with bit width.  It may happen with contrived FP types narrower than [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).

---

Note: `tan()` first step is argument reduction to the primary range [-π/2...π/2].  This, IMO, is harder to do well than primary `tan()` evaluation.  Thus the quality (or lack) of a `tan()` implementation may yield dramatically larger (and incorrect) results with values near `some_odd_n*π/2`.

---

> I'm looking for either some mathematical argument/proof/exhaustive test that shows this does not happen,

See "using the continued fraction related to π" (ref 6) in linked above article for ideas about how the worst case was determined.

Comment: See also: Roger Alan Smith, "A Continued-Fraction Analysis of Trigonometric Argument Reduction", *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 44, No. 11, November 1995, pp. 1348-1351. "We present a simple method using continued fractions for determining, for all numbers x represented in an IEEE floating-point format, the specific x for which the greatest number of insignificant leading bits occur."

Comment: Also based on the use of continued fractions is [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/testpi/nearpi.c) from W. Kahan by way of S. McDonald: "Nearpi, a C program to exhibit large floating-point numbers Z = m * 2 ^ L very close to integer multiples of  pi / 2".

Answer (score 1):

The precision of floating-point values is dictated by IEEE and will always be the same, as long as you use IEEE floating point numbers. In particular, the 32-bit IEEE numbers closest to π/2 are 1.57079637050628662109375 (above) and 1.5707962512969970703125 (below). These values are exact. The mathematically correct values of tangent at these two numbers are not particularly large, about -2.2E7 and 1.3E7, which is rather far from the IEEE-754 limit of ~3E38 for 32-bit binary numbers.

This, however, tells nothing about the behaviour of `tan` for large arguments. First, there is absolutely no guarantee that a library function will return a result closest to the mathematically correct value (*especially* for large arguments). Second, for some odd number N, the representation of N*π/2 could land sufficiently close to the true mathematical value to yield a value of `tan` outside of the representable range. These two observations combined mean that one needs to exhaustively test a particular implementation of `tan` for all values of interest.

Comment: “exhaustively test… for all values of interest” is a bit unclear. Certainly it is not necessary to exhaustively test all representable values; there are number theoretic techniques for identifying the closest value in each binade (exponent interval), so one only needs to test those. On the other hand, one does need to test or exclude all of those above 1 (for lower exponents, the argument is less than π/2). That gives 2045 values “of interest” (exponents 2 to 2046, for IEEE-754 binary64). I would not describe testing 2045 values out of nearly 2^64 as “exhaustive.”

Comment: Re “The precision of floating-point values is dictated by IEEE”: IEEE-754 prescribes certain base formats and permits infinitely many other formats.

Comment: Generally, for one working with implementations of these functions, some properties of the implementation are known, such as that it has some known error bound, so that not just any argument could overflow. If the error bound is such that the representable value closest to an odd multiple of π/2 does not overflow even with the maximum error, then no other representable value will overflow either. True, this does require white-box testing rather than black-box testing.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI, "there is absolutely no guarantee that a library function will return a result closest to the mathematically correct value" is a very good point. A less than ideal `tan(x)` could return infinity for some `x`. OP's <at least with "reasonably correct" library implementations> negates the case here, yet your point is valid in general as `tan(x)`, out in the wild, could return _huge_ values.